# Running OpenFiler inside XenServer to provide Storage to other Xen instances

Tags: virtualization, iscsi, xenserver, openfiler

I'm setting up a Testbed to run some tests on Xen, since I would like to use live migration I was thinking about using iSCSI as a storage, but I only got 2 machines for my quick setup. So my idea is to run OpenFiler inside XenServer A to provide storage for the VMs on itself and XenServer B. 
My question is this even possible? I guess XenServer B have no Problem, but I'm confused if XenServer A, if it can use a VM running on itself as an iSCSI target.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just found the answer myself, just for anybody looking for it there is a KB Entry about that by Citrix http://support.citrix.com/article/CTX118735

Answer (score 1):

There is really no reason why this shouldn't work. You are just running a specific OS on top of XenServer with a specific application that is an iSCSI target.

Just to be clear, this is a really bad idea for anything other then a temporary low IO testbed.

Comment: Yeah I know, just need it for testing, performance is not important, besides running at all, usable.